# I want when my ajax request doesn't go as expected that the user is redirected to a page (Symfony 6)

Tags: ajax, symfony

in my program I am trying to add a character to an ajax game. When the character could not be added, I would like the user to be returned to the previous page with an error message (addflash).

**script.js**

```
function ajouterPerso(){
        const IdPerso = this.parentNode.id;
        const IdPartie = document.querySelector('.recherchePersos').id;
        const Url = new URL(window.location.href);
        fetch(Url.pathname + '?idperso=' + IdPerso + '&idpartie=' + IdPartie + '&ajax=ajoutPerso', {
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
            } 
        }).then(response =>
            response.json()
        ).then(data => {
            const content = document.querySelector('.persosAjoutes');
            content.innerHTML = data.content;
            this.parentNode.remove();
        }).catch(e => alert(e));
    }
```

**and the part use in the controller**

```
if($request->get('ajax') == 'ajoutPerso' && $request->get('idperso') !== null && $request->get('idpartie') !== null){
            $partie = $partieRepository->findOneById($request->get('idpartie'));
            $perso = $persoRepository->findOneById($request->get('idperso'));
            $tableauClasses = $classeRepository->findClassesInPartie($partie);
            if ($partie->getPersos()->count() < 4 && $partie->getOrganisateur() == $user && !(in_array($perso->getClasse()->getId(), $tableauClasses)) && $perso->getPartie() == null) {
                $partie->addPerso($perso);
                $em->persist($partie);
                $em->flush();
                return new JsonResponse(['content' => $this->renderView('partie/_persosAjoutes.html.twig', [
                    'persosAjoutes' => $partie->getPersos()
                ])]);
            } else {
                $this->addFlash('danger', 'L\'ajout du personnage ne s\'est pas passé comme prévu.');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_partie');
            }
        }
```

When the program enters the else, it sends me in Json the HTML code of the page where the user must be sent. How can I prevent my program from necessarily waiting for this response in Json?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just return the route url in a `JsonResponse`, then look for it in script.js and set `window.location.href` to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add success true or false in josn response and also generate url with generateUrl

```
if ($partie->getPersos()->count() < 4 && $partie->getOrganisateur() == $user && !(in_array($perso->getClasse()->getId(), $tableauClasses)) && $perso->getPartie() == null) {
            $partie->addPerso($perso);
            $em->persist($partie);
            $em->flush();
            return new JsonResponse(['success'=> true,
              'content' => $this->renderView('partie/_persosAjoutes.html.twig', [
              'persosAjoutes' => $partie->getPersos()
            ])]);
        } else {
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'L\'ajout du personnage ne s\'est pas passé comme prévu.');
            return new JsonResponse(['success'=> false,'url' => $this->generateUrl('app_partie')])
        }
```

and in js code you check the value of success , if is false you do

```
 window.location.href = data.url
```